# Why is limit 0,1 slower than limit 0, 17

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to analyze why the following query is slower with `LIMIT 0,1` than `LIMIT 0,100`

I've added `SQL_NO_CACHE` for testing purposes.

Query:

```
 SELECT 
  SQL_NO_CACHE  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, 
  low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS low_stock_amount
FROM 
  wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS low_stock_amount_meta ON wp_posts.ID = low_stock_amount_meta.post_id 
  AND low_stock_amount_meta.meta_key = '_low_stock_amount' 
WHERE 
  1 = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
  AND (
    (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  ) 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity IS NOT NULL 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_status IN('instock', 'outofstock') 
  AND (
    (
      low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value > '' 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= CAST(
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS SIGNED
      )
    ) 
    OR (
      (
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value IS NULL 
        OR low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value <= ''
      ) 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= 2
    )
  ) 

ORDER BY 
  wp_posts.ID DESC 
LIMIT 
  0, 1
```

Explains shows the exact same output

```
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    index   PRIMARY,type_status_date    PRIMARY 8   NULL    27071   Using where
1   SIMPLE  low_stock_amount_meta   ref post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  wc_product_meta_lookup  eq_ref  PRIMARY,stock_status,stock_quantity,product_id  PRIMARY 8   woocommerce-admin.wp_posts.ID   1   Using where
```

The average query time is 350ms with `LIMIT 0,1`

The average query time is 7ms with `LIMIT 0,100`

The query performance gets faster starting with `LIMIT 0,17`

I've added another column to the order by clause as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1/27237698#27237698), but that triggers `Using filesort` in the explain output

`Order by wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.ID desc`

```
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    ALL PRIMARY,type_status_date    NULL    NULL    NULL    27071   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  low_stock_amount_meta   ref post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  wc_product_meta_lookup  eq_ref  PRIMARY,stock_status,stock_quantity,product_id  PRIMARY 8   woocommerce-admin.wp_posts.ID   1   Using where
```

Is there a way to work around it without altering indices and why is this happening?

It's also interesting that the query time improves starting with `LIMIT 0,17`. I'm not sure why 17 is a magic number here.

Update 1: I just tried adding `FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)` and now `LIMIT 0,100` has the same performance as `LIMIT 0,1` smh

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running these queries against?

Comment: @matigo This is 5.6.38

Comment: that is very old, and has minor updates already up to 5.6.51

Comment: This is a cross-post.

Comment: Hi Moon, Can try execute with first ```limit 0,17``` & then execute ```LIMIT 0,1```  ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI I. know what you're trying to do :) LIMIT 0,17 is still faster on the first run.